# TextArea field set to Auto br / isn't adding break point tag

Tags: fields, formatting

I have a field with formatting set to Auto br /. If I add a line of content, hit Enter, and add another line it appears it would work. But on the front end the break isn't there. If I edit that entry again it still appears as two lines in the field. But It appears on one line on the front end. Any ideas? possible bug? Thanks for any info!

Comment: What version of EE?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your template. It's possible a plugin tag is wrapped around your field tag and removing all html tags from the copy or specifically removing `<br />` tags

Comment: Anna, It's within a Google map plugin tag, but it shouldn't be stripping anything. if I manually add the brak tag to the content in the field it will break on the front end.

Comment: What version of EE are you running? Try upgrading to v2.5.5 to make sure it's not a bug on your current version. Also, make sure you are running the most recent Google Map addon version.

Comment: I'm using EE 2.5.5 and the most recent version of Google Maps addon :/